# Бот пересылает только первое фото и текст

Tags: python, алгоритм

Нужно чтобы бот переслал всё содержимое в сообщении, в заявке может быть до 3 фото, но бот пересылает только первое фото и текст.

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: True)

def callback(callback):

    if callback.data == 'input_kos':
            send_kos = bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Отправь 2-3 фото и описание ️\nНе забудь указать свои контакты ‼️⬇')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(send_kos, app_kos)

def app_kos(message):

   if message.content_type == 'text' or 'photo':

        bot.forward_message(chat_id=chatAdministration, from_chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.id)
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Ваша заявка будет рассмотрена администратором ✅')
    else:
        error = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Что-то пошло не так')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(error, app_kos)
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Или есть вариант как можно поступить по другому? В copy_message точно такая история

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: А где декоратор у второй функции? Он там ведь должен тоже быть?

Comment: это ведь функция для register_next_step_handler. Она прекрасно работает